# Is there any PowerPoint alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, presentation

Is there any PowerPoint alternative? I'm not looking for just a viewer but also a presentation maker.

Comment: LibreOffice Impress

Answer (score 6):

Well, There are many programs to make Presentation:

- [OpenOffice/LibreOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/),
- [KOficce](http://www.koffice.org/download/),
- [GnomeOffice](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeOffice)
- Microsoft Office(using Wine) !

you can also use

### Google Docs (Web: Free)

> Google Docs Updates Presentations With Real-Time Collaboration, New
> Themes, Transitions and More Google Docs has rolled out a new version
> of its presentations tool with over 50 new features, including,
> simultaneous editing, a series of new slide… Read… Google Docs'
> presentations module used to be fairly lackluster, but they've updated
> it recently to make it more compatible with people coming over from
> Microsoft Office, or people who want a more robust presentations tool.

### [Beamer (LaTeX) (Windows/Mac/Linux: Free)](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/wiki/Home)

> If you're a fan of LaTeX, or just remember having to apply it for your
> graduate thesis, you'll love Beamer. Where other presentation tools
> give you a GUI where you drag in elements you want to use like images
> and video and then tweak text boxes to include the information you
> want on screen, Beamer requires you to build your presentation in a
> custom markup language that works for just about any LaTeX document.

http://lifehacker.com/5888189/five-best-powerpoint-alternatives

Answer (score 3):

Impress is a truly outstanding tool for creating effective multimedia presentations. Presentation edition and creation is flexible, thanks to different editing and view modes
http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/

OpenLaszlo is an open source development platform for web applications. It's main target today is generating macromedia flash files (swf)and AJAX/DHTML for use on web pages and sites.
http://www.openlaszlo.org

KPresenter is the open source presentations part of the KOffice suite. Excellent for combining text and graphics into slides either for on-screen presentation and handouts.
http://www.kde.org/applications/office/kpresenter/

Answer (score 2):

**LibreOffice Impress**

Use LibreOffice Impress for create a presentation, it's an default presentation program for Ubuntu.

**Google Presentation**

Google's web application is used to create presentations.

**NEW !! Microsoft PowerPoint online**

Now microsoft office opened on the web !!! Visit this [site](https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx?ui=en-US) for PowerPoint online

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First hit would be LibreOffice Impress.

Web based (but quite good for some purposes) - Prezi

Answer (score -1):

OpenOffice.org is also a good alternative.